# Как скрыть поля от определеных пользователей GridView

Tags: yii2

Я у пользователей ввел правило `canViewsSite`, мне нужно в случае если у пользователя нет такого разрешения, то что бы поля не выводились.
Пытался сделать так в представлении:

```
$gridColums=[
        [
            'attribute'=>'key_feild',
            'value'    => function($model){
                return $model->canViewsKeyFeild($model);
            }
      ],
       [
            'attribute'=>'value',
            'value'    => function($model){
                return $model->canViewsValue($model);
            },
       ],
     ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ];
```

Вот в модели:

```
public function canViewsKeyFeild($model){
        if($model->key_feild=='site'){
            if(Yii::$app->user->can('canViewsSite')){
                return $model->key_feild;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return $model->key_feild;
        }
    }
```

Но тут возникает ошибка, поле есть, оно просто не заполнено, а при редактировании вообще можно зайти и все увидеть. Можно ли как-то скрыть поля в случае если у пользователя нет правила `canViewsSite` и значение

```
keyfeild == 'site'
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть параметр [visible](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$visible-detail)

```
$gridColumns = [
    [
        'attribute' => 'key_feild',
        'visible' => Yii::$app->user->can('canViewsSite'),
    ],
    [
        'attribute' => 'value',
        'visible' => Yii::$app->user->can('canViewsSite'),
    ],
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
];
```